# Sind »bei« und »auf« austauschbar?

Tags: difference, preposition

> Wir waren gestern **auf** dem Empfang meines Bruders.
>
> Wir waren gestern **bei** dem Empfang meines Bruders.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *bei* und *auf* in diesen Sätzen? Sind sie austauschbar? Warum? Danke!

Answer (score 6):

Meinem Sprachempfinden zufolge beinhaltet "auf dem Empfang" die Bedeutung, dass man an der Veranstaltung teilgenommen hat, während "bei dem Empfang" etwas mehr Abstand impliziert, oder auch verwendet werden könnte, wenn beispielsweise ein Ereignis beschrieben wird, welches am Rande des Empfangs (auch noch) stattgefunden hat, allerdings ohne allzu starken Bezug zur Veranstaltung.

Answer (score 4):

**Ich beschreibe weiter unten meine Gepflogenheiten (und die meiner Familie), aber ich habe überrascht festgestellt, dass es auch kultivierte Muttersprachler gibt, welche viel flexibler sind**.

Mit »Empfang« würde ich stets nur *auf* verwenden, habe aber keine andere Quelle als mein Sprachempfinden.

Dies gilt auch für dem Empfang ähnliche Anlässe. »Die Gala«, »das Fest«, »die Beerdigung«, »die Taufe« … Die Gemeinsamkeit dieser Anlässe besteht offenbar im zeremoniellen Charakter.

Dabei muss man unterscheiden, ob man von der Taufe als Festivität oder aber als Handlung spricht. Ich würde im Folgenden nie »bei« verwenden:

> Wir waren heute auf einer Taufe.

Wohl aber sagen:

> Mein Bruder schrie bei der Taufe.

Hier geht es schließlich um die Taufe als Handlung, so dass man auch schreiben könnte:

> Mein Bruder schrie, als man ihn taufte.

Und Gleiches gilt für den Empfang, so dass ich den Satz:

> Mein Bruder sagte etwas Falsches, als er den Botschafter empfing,

und ***nicht*** den Satz:

> Mein Bruder sagte auf dem Empfang des Botschafters etwas Falsches,

als korrektes Analogon des folgenden betrachte:

> Mein Bruder sagte beim Empfang des Botschafters etwas Falsches.

Comment: Ich kann an »Ich war bei einem Empfang« oder »Wir waren heute bei einer Taufe« nichts finden, weswegen ich diese Sätze nicht verwenden sollte.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast wirklich! Dann werde ich es einarbeiten, dass meine Gepflogenheiten offenbar nicht dem Standard entsprechen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Wie erzeugen Sie die schönen Guillemets? Ich versuche sie zu übernehmen, kann aber nur Gänsefüßchen schreiben :(

Comment: Ich verwende einen Mac (von Apple). Das öffnende Chevron (») ist shift+alt+Q. Das schließende Chevron («) ist alt+Q. Tastenkombinationen auf Computern mit anderen Betriebssystemen als OS X kenne ich leider nicht. Noch eine Anmerkung: In Frankreich und der Schweiz verwendet man «Guilemets» (die Pfeile zeigen nach außen). In Deutschland und Österreich verwendet man dagegen die nach innen gerichteten »Chevrons«. (Es sind dieselben Zeichen, sie heißen aber anders wenn man sie anders verwendet).

Comment: @Ludi Auf Windows Alt-0187 (die Ziffern mit der Zehnertastatur eingeben) für *»* und Alt-0171 für *«*. Auf Linux ist der Standard oft Alt Gr+y und Alt Gr+x; ich habe sowohl die Kombination y = » und x = « wie auch umgekehrt auf deutschsprachig (Deutschland) eingerichteten Linuxen gefunden, also ausprobieren.

Answer (score 3):

In Duden ‒ *Das Stilwörterbuch* werden beide Varianten gleichwertig nebeneinander genannt:

> auf/bei einem Empfang in der deutschen Botschaft

Das bestätigt aber lediglich, dass beide Ausdrücke im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch vorkommen. Über eventuelle Bedeutungsunterschiede sagt das nichts aus.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn man *bei* und *auf* auf Veranstaltungen bezieht, kann man die Präpositionen wie in deinem Beispiel im normalen Sprachgebrauch austauschen, dadurch werden keine Missverständnisse entstehen.

Nur wenn es hingegen um die genaue räumliche Beschreibung geht, machen diese beiden Präpositionen einen Unterschied 
aus.

> Ich bin bei dem Gebäude aber nicht auf dem Gebäude.